# How to create progress bars in obsidian dataview

Tags: javascript, obsidian, obsidian-dataview

I want to create progress bars to see my advancements during the year in different topics along the year in Obsidian.

I've checked several options, like this tutorial, but don't seem clear to me:
[Progress Bar on Tasks](https://obsidianttrpgtutorials.com/Obsidian+TTRPG+Tutorials/Plugin+Tutorials/Dataview/DataviewJS+-+Progress+Bar+on+Tasks)

In the following example they provide:

```
(await dv.tryQuery('TASK FROM "Test" ')).values.length
const Tasks = dv.page("Test").file.tasks

let CompletedTasks = Tasks
    .where(t => t.completed)

dv.span(
    "![progress](https://progress-bar.dev/"
    + parseInt((CompletedTasks.length / Tasks.length) * 100)
    + "/)"
)
```

and

```
- [ ] Quest 1
- [ ] Quest 2
- [ ] Quest 3
- [ ] Quest 4
- [ ] Quest 5
```

What do I have to modify to obtain a progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you linked work out of the box for me. Let's see how they operate.

## Web progress bar

[image]

This progress bar gets embedded from a website called https://progress-bar.dev/, which generates on-demand pictures of progress bars. The [DataviewJS](https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/api/intro/) looks like this:

```js
const Tasks = dv.page("Test").file.tasks
    
let CompletedTasks = Tasks
    .where(t => t.completed)
    
dv.span(
    "![progress](https://progress-bar.dev/"
    + parseInt((CompletedTasks.length / Tasks.length) * 100)
    + "/)"
)
```

1. Fetches the `tasks` (checkboxes) from a page called `"Test"` and stores the result as `Tasks`.
2. Copies the **completed** tasks into another variable, `CompletedTasks`.
3. Constructs a URL in the shape of `https://progress-bar.dev/80/`, calculating the percentage as `(Tasks / CompletedTasks) * 100` and rounding off the decimals with `parseInt()`.
4. Embeds the picture in normal Markdown: [image]

## HTML progress bar

[image]

This one is a native HTML progress bar, so it works **offline**, and can be customized with CSS if you want to. The example uses an [inline DataviewJS query](https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/queries/dql-js-inline/#inline-dataview-js), which I'll break into separate lines here:

```js
const value = Math.round((
  (dv.current().file.tasks.where(t => t.completed).length) / (dv.current().file.tasks).length || 0
) * 100);

"<progress value='" + value + "' max='100'></progress>" + " " + value + "%"
```

1. Calculates the percentage as `tasks.where(t => t.completed).length` divided by `file.tasks.length`, and rounds the number with `Math.round()` (using `0` as a fallback if the tasks don't load).
2. Stores the percentage as `value`.
3. Creates an HTML progress bar by concatenating strings together, which spits out: `<progress value='80' max='100'></progress> 80%`

## Using this code yourself

You can choose which note the progress bars use by calling either `dv.current()` or `dv.page("My note")` to choose a different note. For anything else you need to do, read through the [Dataview documentation](https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/) and learn about its JavaScript API.

https://progress-bar.dev/ actually has some extra commands to customize the bar too, like `title` and `scale`, and you can see some examples on their GitHub.

Good luck designing a fun Obsidian dashboard!

Comment: Thanks @Holo, that was very helpful. However, I'm very new to JS and Obsidian as well. I understand what the code is doing. `const value` to compute the 'value' variable, and the last line is to insert the bar. However, if I just cp/paste your code nothing prompts, I just see the code. I don't know how to transform the chunk of code into the actual bar...

Comment: @roybatty A few things! I'm guessing you already installed the Dataview plugin - look in your plugin settings, and make sure JavaScript queries are enabled (they're disabled by default).

Comment: @roybatty Then for any code you paste, make sure it's wrapped in the DataviewJS syntax ([read this page](https://blacksmithgu.github.io/obsidian-dataview/queries/dql-js-inline/#dataview-js)), or the plugin won't recognize your code.